# GLSL(1.2) + VBOs + Textures

Tags: c++, c, glsl

Again applying their considerable help with a problem. This is my code:

```
  float ctex[] = {0.0,0.0,
                  0.0,1.0,
                  1.0,1.0,
                  1.0,0.0};

  float data[] = {1.0, 1.0,-5.0,
                 -1.0,-1.0,-5.0,
                  1.0,-1.0,-5.0,
                 -1.0, 1.0,-5.0};
  GLuint ind[] = {0,1,2,0,3,1};     

      LoadTexture();  

      glGenBuffers(1,&triangleVBO);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleVBO);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(data),data,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      glGenBuffers(1,&triangleIND);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleIND);
      glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(ind),ind,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

      glGenBuffers(1,&triangleT[0]);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleT[0]);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(ctex),ctex,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

      GLuint v,f,p;
      v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
      f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      p = glCreateProgram();

      char *vsFuente = LeeShader("shaders/shader.vert");
      char *fsFuente = LeeShader("shaders/shader.frag");

      const char *vs = vsFuente;
      const char *fs = fsFuente;

      glShaderSource(v,1,&vs,NULL);
      glShaderSource(f,1,&fs,NULL);
      free(vsFuente);free(fsFuente);

      glCompileShader(v);
      glCompileShader(f);

      glAttachShader(p,v);
      glAttachShader(p,f);

      glLinkProgram(p);

      //main loop
      while(1){
        ...etc.

              glUseProgram(p);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleVBO);
                  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
                  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleTex);
                  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
                  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,idtextere);
                  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
              glUseProgram(0);

        ...etc.
      }
```

This is my Vertex Shader:

```
void main(){
  gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
  gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

And this my Fragment Shader:

uniform sampler2D tex;

```
void main(){
  vec4 color = texture2D(tex,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The problem is that the texture does not appear or anything else. I could say What's the problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); ?

Comment: yep, I use it but nothing

Comment: `texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(yourID, textureUniformName); glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);`

Comment: @Borgleader `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D` is absolutely unneccessary when using shaders, that's for old fixed-function texturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old fixed-function attributes in your shader (like `gl_MultiTexCoord0` or `gl_Vertex` as used by `ftransform`). But in your application code you try to load them with the generic attribute interface (like `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`). This won't work (it might work for attribute 0, which is an alias for `gl_Vertex`, though, but that's counter-intuitive anyway).

There are two way to fix this. Either don't use the generic attribute API, but the old fixed-function attributes, so replace `glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...)` with `glVertexPointer` and `glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...)` with `glTexCoordPointer` and likewise `glEnableVertexAttribArray` with `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` and `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)`.

Or, the more modern and future-proof approach, drop the usage of the old fixed-function stuff inside your shaders and put in your attributes as generic attributes:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_TexCoord[0] = texCoord;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

And don't forget to call `glBindAttribLocation(p, 0, "position")` and `glBindAttribLocation(p, 1, "texCoord")` before linking the program in order to assign the attribute indices to the correct attributes.

But the second approach, even if preferred, might be a bit too heavy a change for you right now, since it should actually be accompanied by dropping any use of old fixed-function stuff inside your shaders, like the modelview projection matrix, which should rather be a custom uniform, or the `gl_TexCoord[0]` varying, which should rather be a custom varying.

Comment: phew, finally works. I had to use UV = coordtex instead of gl_TexCoord [0] = texCoord, . Where UV is a varying vec2 variable and coordtex is a attribute vec2 variable. This because gl_TexCoord [0] is not a vec2 variable. Thank you very much for your help friend.

Comment: *"This because gl_TexCoord [0] is not a vec2 variable"* - Well, you could have just assigned it to the 2D part and left rest to default, like `gl_TexCoord[0] = vec4(texCoord, 0.0, 1.0);` or `gl_TexCoord[0].st = texCoord;`, or you could have taken the attribute as `vec4` and let the GL fill it's r and q coordinates with the defaults.